# Is passing a piece of data from child component to parent component an anti pattern in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

consider the following example...

I have a component called ChemVisualisation.jsx it is as follows

```
const ChemVisualization = props => {

 const { getChemists, chemists } = props;

 useEffect(() => {
    getChemists();
  }, [getChemists]);

// useState hook is used here 
// handleChange sets the name property
// i check for chemists based on name property here and pass it as props to 
// SearchableDropdown component where it renders the list 

 const getChemistId = id => {
    console.log(id);
    // showing undefined
  };

return(
 <SearchableDropdown
            getName={ChemistAnalytics}
            onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}
            entities={result}
            handleClick={getChemistId}
          />
);
}
```

SearchableDropdown.jsx

```
const SearchableDropdown = props => {

// destructure props here
return(
<div className="control has-icons-left w-3/5 ">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="search"
          value={value}
          name={name}
          onChange={onChange}
          className="input"
          autoComplete="off"
        />
        <span className="icon is-left">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch}></FontAwesomeIcon>
        </span>
      </div>
      {entities && (
        <div className="dropdown">
          <div className="dropdown-content">
            {entities.map(r => (
              <div
                className="dropdown-item text-xl hover:bg-gray-400 w-full"
                key={r._id}
                onClick={r => handleClick(r._id)}
              >
                {r.chem_name}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
);
}
```

When I click the drop down item, I'm not getting the id in its parent component.

My question is how do I get the id of the drop down item that I clicked?
Is passing the data from child component to its parent an anti-pattern?

Comment: I think `r._id` is undefined because that onClick function is passing the onclick event `r` as `handleClick` parameter instead of the r from entities mapping block. IMO, it's easier to maintain components with states that are flown in a single direction.

Comment: What would you recommend as a solution?

Comment: Lifting your state up should be a fine solution. So you'd have a `Container` that contains state and handlers, these would be passed down to the child components that can then be optimized as `PureComponents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal for child components to call functions their parents provide to them in response to events. The parent then rerenders as necessary with the new information. This keeps the state information fairly "high." More in [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up) in the documentation.

In your example with

```
<div className="dropdown-content">
  {entities.map(r => (
    <div
      className="dropdown-item text-xl hover:bg-gray-400 w-full"
      key={r._id}
      onClick={r => handleClick(r._id)}
    >
      {r.chem_name}
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

the problem is that you're shadowing `r` (the parameter of the `map` callback) with a different `r` (the parameter of the `onClick`). The first argument the click handler is called with is an event object. If you don't want it, just don't accept the parameter:

```
<div className="dropdown-content">
  {entities.map(r => (
    <div
      className="dropdown-item text-xl hover:bg-gray-400 w-full"
      key={r._id}
      onClick={() => handleClick(r._id)}
    >
      {r.chem_name}
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

The only change there is replacing `r` with `()` in `onClick={() => handleClick(r._id)}`.

Comment: I've seen many versions of event handlers what do they mean ```onClick={e => handleChange(e)}``` and this ```onClick={handleChange}```   ```handleChange(event) { //do something here}``` when do we actually require teh first version?

Comment: @Yashwanthsomayajula - You need `onClick={() => handleClick(r._id)}` in this case because what you want to pass to `handleClick` is the value of the `_id` property of the `r` object. If it accepted an event object instead, then yes, you could do just `onClick={handleClick}` or `onClick={e => handleClick(e)}` (though the latter is pointless, do the former). But if you want to pass in that ID value, you want `onClick={() => handleClick(r._id)}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick={e => handleClick(r._id)}
```

Use e instead of r.

Comment: Or nothing at all, since it's not used.